# Monotouch storyboard MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: xamarin.ios

This code works in a non-storyboard environment but only shows a black screen when run on a storyboard ViewController. Not sure what the difference would be. Suggestions welcome

```
public partial class videoVC : UIViewController
{

    MPMoviePlayerController mp = new MPMoviePlayerController();

    public videoVC (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();
        this.buttonPlay.TouchUpInside += delegate {
        try{

            mp = new MPMoviePlayerController(NSUrl.FromFilename("videos/file.m4v"));
            mp.AllowsAirPlay = true;
            this.View.AddSubview(mp.View);
            mp.SetFullscreen(true,true);
            mp.PrepareToPlay();
            mp.Play();

            }catch{

            Console.WriteLine("There was a problem playing back Video");

            }       

        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the Build Action property of the file.m4v set to Content?